# Can neutrophils kill bacteria inside other cells?

Tags: cell-biology, immunology, immune-system

Are neutrophils able to get inside epithelial cells in order to kill bacteria. Therefore, even if a bacteria gets inside the epithelial cells can the neutrophils get inside the epithelium to kill the bacteria?

Also when the bacteria get into blood stream can neutrophils kill the bacteria?

I am not from a biology background. So, a simple explanation will be helpful

Comment: Please do some basic reading on [neutrophils](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrophil) (or whatever your topic is) before you post a question. We want to help clear up confusion or solve problems in people with a sincere interest in Biology. But we do ask for evidence (in the question) of what you read about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are neutrophils able to get inside epithelial cells in order to kill bacteria. 
>   Therefore, even if a bacteria gets inside the epithelial cells can the neutrophils get inside the epithelium to kill the bacteria?

**No**. Firstly because bacteria (except for very special cases) do not enter epithelial(or other) cells - that's what viruses do. Second, neutrophils recognise bacteria based on markers on their cell wall. These markers can come from the bacteria themselves, or from the innate immune system (see [complement system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_system)) that 'marks' the bacteria, in any case being inside another cell would protect bacteria from neutrophils. Cases are like these are handled by the CD8+ T-cells of the adaptive immune system.

> Also when the bacteria get into blood stream can neutrophils kill the bacteria?

**Yes**, that's their job and neutrophils are usually inside of the blood(stream), so they could find and kill bacteria there.